# Azure B2C Custom Flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an application that uses Azure B2C to login to an application that calls an API - using the user flow SUSI, I get info in the claim that identifies the user, so I get the login or email address.

I want to use it for SSO with other MS tenants and possibly in the future Google - I have followed the various guides and uploaded the TrustFrameworkBase, Localization, Extension and SignUpOrSignIn XML files.  The login appears to work, in that it offers a signin option against Microsoft and lets me login, but the claims that are passed to by API does not provide the other tenant ID, user ID etc - the information all relates to the local tenant.  I d not get any login/email address info so I am not able to tie it back to records in my DB.

My latest SignUpOrSignIn file is based on this one: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/user-info-endpoint/policy/UserInfo_SignUpOrSignin.xml
using JWT.MS as a call back, the response is similar to this:

```
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
  "kid": "##l5oIPM31fXvTQA6jSNJJfFifuIxVl7xvJf5UHuPxY",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://####.b2clogin.com/##cbc16c-147c-4662-b581-933476086d57/v2.0/",
  "sub": "##f120af-77f2-49f4-8d28-2cc4bdcd25f7",
  "aud": "##50964c-2cbf-4cfa-966c-030e72c3be81",
  "exp": 1694428197,
  "acr": "b2c_1a_signup_signin",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": 1694424597,
  "auth_time": 1694424597,
  "name": "Mike",
  "family_name": "C",
  "tid": "##cbc16c-147c-4662-b581-933476086d57",
  "nbf": 1694424597
}.[Signature]
```

I have followed various guides to get the XML files correct and add claims, the latest iteration is simply

```
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
  </OutputClaims>
```

but I do not appear to get anything back that is identifiable.  I don't need all user details, but I do need something to be able to link the users ID to records in a local database

Answer (score 0):

> but the claims that are passed to by API does not provide the other tenant ID, user ID etc - the information all relates to the local tenant.

The tenant is derived from the domain in which the user logs into. Sending that down would be superfluous.

But its unclear why you are not getting the email address. Let us remove the app/tenant from the

The `userId` is sent down as a claim found in `oid` claim.

To Resolve follow these steps in the B2C Portal while running a flow from there:

1. *Temporarily* add `https://jwt.ms` as a `Redirect URIs` for the registered app(s) in question in the `App Registrations` section.
2. In the Run a flow, verify that `Email Addresses` are selected as an output flow item in `Application Claims`.
3. Run the flow in question (`Run user flow` by hand and set the reply url drop down to the jwt.ms selection which you added for the app in step 1.

View the result shows all things selected such as `emails` and `oid`.